# Do Google Play Store allows bookmark apps?

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps, bookmarks

We are making a very small app that will be just a bookmark app.
It will just be installed on the device and when someone clicks on the icon, we will open our specified URL.
This is the only purpose of the app. We want to confirm that is this type of application allowed on Play store?
Can we upload this app on Play store and would this be approved?

Answer (score 2):

You can upload an App to the Play Store that only contains a link to a Web URL.  This is allowed on the Play Store.

Reference this document (titled: "Google Play Apps Policy Center") for details on what is approved and what is not: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4430948?hl=en&rd=1